# bibtex aux-files directory

Tags: bibtex, miktex, biber, auxiliary-files, output

### Preamble: Setting the output directories

TeX distros have the useful command line option `--output-directory` to create all output files in a specified directory.

MikTeX provides an even more convenient  option to put only temporary material in a separate folder, which can be eventually deleted, that is:

```
pdflatex --aux-directory=auxdir mybook
```

`--aux-directory` is particularly convenient for large projects with several TeX files, for example a book with several chapters, to reduce post-compilation clutter.

One can use together `--aux-directory` and `--output-directory`.
Below I will address `--aux-directory`, but using `--output-directory` or both produces the same issue.

### Using bibliographies when output/aux directories are diverted

I haven't yet tried them, but I am aware of `--input-directory` and `--output_directory` option, which should do similar jobs in `biber`.

As regards BibTeX, there are no such options. For a simple project, based on a single `.tex` file (and therefore `.aux`), depending on your path separator,

```
bibtex auxdir/mybook 
bibtex auxdir\mybook
```

should work. If there are several `.tex` files (when the aux dir is actually useful),  `bibtex` is unable to find the other aux files, which will still be searched in the project's root dir.

It is possible to cd to `auxdir`, but in this case the `.bib` and `.bst` files will not be found.
A workaround consists in copying them in the `auxdir`. That works, but it is against the purpose of such directory and also time-consuming, as the original `.bib` file in the parent directory is likely to be updated often.

What is the correct workflow for bibtex and biber when the `--aux-directory` (`--output-directory`) option is employed?

Comment: Unlike `bibtex`, `biber` has an `--output-directory` flag that handles this properly.

Comment: Well *my* workflow is not to use the --aux-directory and --output-directory switches. While .log, .pdf, .blg are real output files, almost all other files are actually **input** files, so I find it quite illogical to move them to an output folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Generally, I tend to do like you do, but for a book with several chapters, this is too much stress. Apart from definitions (which are always slippery), folders exist for a reason: organising files when a flat structure doesn't fit.

Comment: I do find it much more stressing to constantly have to switch a folder to find some file.

Comment: Some LaTeX editors have options to delete aux files. e. g. Texmaker `Tools --> Clean`. This is what I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So some suggestions:

**1. Don't use `--output-directory` or `--aux-directory`**

Really. They just add a whole layer of unnecessary complexity. In addition to issues with `bibtex`, if you have use multiple input files, you'll likely end up having to recreate the same folder hierarchy in the output directory as you have in the main directory. Especially for large, multi-part documents, this can be a hassle for no real added value. Similarly, if you use other external tools, you'll end up needing to configure them to use the output directory appropriately.

**2. Use `latexmk`**

This will handle `bibtex` in an appropriate way and handle the issue with the output hierarchy detailed above. This is probably the simplest way to deal with things, if you insist on using an output directory.

**3. A way to make things work**

If you still want to use an output directory and don't want to use `latexmk`, you can do the same thing that `latexmk` does. From the command prompt, you can run `bibtex` like this (all one line):

`cd auxdir & set BIBINPUTS="C:\path\to\mybook;%BIBINPUTS%" & set BSTINPUTS="C:\path\to\mybook;%BSTINPUTS%" & bibtex mybook`

Which runs `bibtex` in the auxdir, while adding the directory containing the source files to the bib / bst search path.

Comment: +1 Especially for 1. `--output-directory` and friends create much more problems than they solve. Especially new users seem to like the 'use 'build' directory'-like options in editors, but the problems certainly outweigh the advantages.

Comment: +1 thanks. `BIBINPUTS` solves, but the Windows equivalent of `$BIBINPUTS="/path/to/mybook:%BIBINPUTS%"` is  `set "BIBINPUTS=C:\path\to\mybook;%BIBINPUTS%"` (quotes needed only with space in the paths). However `set` is global and not local to batch scripts, so for every call you would add up the same directory. Assuming current dir is `mybook.tex` dir, then `set BIBINPUTS=auxdir  & bibtex tex-aux-files\main` is sufficient (with relative `auxdir` path).
`BSTINPUTS` is not necessary. If `BIBINPUTS` is already defined, one needs a temp var to keep its value or `setlocal`. Consider fixing!

Comment: @antonio: you’re right about the semicolons, and I’ve fixed that, but *from the CMD prompt*, using `SETLOCAL` instead of `SET` doesn’t work. Things are different in batch files. You’re also right that `BIBINPUTS` largely isn’t needed, but it may be in some cases and is pretty harmless in others. Similarly, the excess quotes may not be necessary, but are harmless and ARE necessary if the `%BIBINPUTS%` variable itself has unquoted spaces (which is perfectly possible).