# Problems in setting texmaker to compile bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, biber, texmaker

I'm currently having problems making a bibliography with texmaker.

First of all I have installed both biber and texlive-bibtex-extra and I'm using texmaker 5.1.2 as an interface in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I downloaded the following code as an example from overleaf:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib} %Import the bibliography file

\begin{document}
Let's cite! Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} [...]

\printbibliography %Prints bibliography

\end{document}
```

`example.bib`

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}
```

If I run bibtex inside texmaker I get the error `` I couldn't open file name `main.aux' ``

Instead if I run on terminal

```
pdflatex main
biber main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

it produced the exact citations.

However, if I try to adapt the configuration inside texmaker as follows

[image]

I get the following error message:

```
Process started

Use of uninitialized value in quotemeta at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Config.pm line 228.

Use of uninitialized value $tool in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Config.pm line 307.

INFO - This is Biber 2.17 INFO - Logfile is 'main_bibliografia.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find 'main_bibliografia.bcf'! INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

How can I solve this problem or how can I print bibliography using texmaker?

Comment: Uncheck the 'Usa la sottodirectory "build" per i file di output' option. "Build" subdirectories rarely play well with additional tools like Biber, `makeindex` and friends. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261123/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471258/35864. (Those links also contain some hints on how you can get Biber to cooperate with "build" subdirectories if you insist on using them.)

Comment: That was brilliant. I just modified the line of compilation with ```biber --output_directory build %``` and it perfectly works. Thank you!

Comment: Just a quick note: The first two messages may appear troubling at first, but they can be safely ignored (and are fixed in the current Biber version 2.18): https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/403.